# Open source accountancy programs?

Tags: open-source, finance

Are there any good open source accountancy programs a startup could use? Double-entry accountancy is required by law in many countries (including mine), so it is a must.

The platform should be either Windows or Linux, "bonus points" if it runs on both.

It would be used in Austria.

Answer (score 12):

### How about [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/)?

I would recommend it based on what I've used it for, however, I am not an accountant nor do I use it professionally. That said, I've found it rather useful for keeping track of finances.

According to its website, it [features](http://www.gnucash.org/features.phtml):

1. Open Source
2. Cross-platform, Windows, Linux, Mac
3. Double-Entry Accounting
4. Stock/Bond/Mutual Fund Accounts
5. Small-Business Accounting
6. Reports, Graphs
7. QIF/OFX/HBCI Import, Transaction Matching
8. Scheduled Transactions
9. Financial Calculations

[image: Screenshot found online]

Also, more information about [Double-entry accounting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system) with GnuCash can be found [here](http://www.gnucash.org/docs/v1.6/C/t2504.html).

Comment: I agree with GnuCash. While it is far from perfect and underperformes when compared to commercial options it is the only real free and/or open-source option available which is decently feature-complete. (based on my research of about 2 years ago)

Comment: @ConfusedStack can you recommend GnuCash, or did you just copy and paste information from their website? Please read [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong?cb=1).

Comment: @Olli I can personally recommend GnuCash, but I got the feature list from their website.

Comment: @ConfusedStack if you can, then please edit your experiences to the answer, preferably more than "I have used it", as there's probably some positive things and issues too.

Answer (score 4):

### Single user or multi-user?

If you are looking for a single-user desktop software, **GnuCash** recommended by @ConfusedStack is the best option (Full disclosure: I am the author of `Gnucash 2.4 Small Business Accounting Beginner's Guide` by Packt Publishing). It even has an Android expense-tracking companion app.

However, if you need multi-user software, you can try **FrontAccounting**. It goes beyond accounting and has some ERP capabilities as well. It has the following modules: Sales, Purchases, Inventory, Manufacturing, Dimensions, Banking and General Ledger. It is suitable for small and medium companies for managing purchases, control stock, send offers, book orders and send invoices. [Here is a review article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-frontaccounting-is-a-free-alternative-to-quickbooks/) and you can read [several user reviews here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/frontaccounting/). You can also [try out an online demo here](http://frontaccounting.com/wb3/pages/home/demo.php).

Comment: For open source multi-user accounting software, there is also [LedgerSMB](https://ledgersmb.org).