# Accounting software for small business

Tags: osx, business-intelligence, accounting

I just started a dry cleaning small business in California. My accounting skills are limited. I am looking for advice on software that can help me manage my finances such as profits, expenses and etc. with ease.

I also want to be able to identify trends in graphs and any other useful insight to improve my business.

A free open source software is great, but I am willing to buy one if it's good and for the right price. I am using Mac.

Comment: Please detail your needs. Every business need different software. Do you have 1 customer, or millions of customers? In what country are you? What legislation do you need to comply to? What is your goal? You tagged business-intelligence, what dimensions do you want to keep track of?

Comment: Peachtree and Quickbooks are 2 of the big ones.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. @NicolasRaoul I am in the U.S. I have a small business - a dry cleaners. I tagged business-intelligence because I want to be able to identify trends in graphs and any other useful insight to improve my business.

Comment: If you want a standalone software (i.e. not a cloud based solution). I suggest that you edit your question to mention it, because there are many providers of web based accounting softwares.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_accounting_software

Answer (score 2):

Here are the most popular:

- [FreeAgent](http://www.freeagent.com/)

  More expensive than QuickBooks, but it offer a lot of more [features](http://www.freeagent.com/tour).
- [QuickBooks](http://quickbooks.intuit.com/)

  Fairly cheap for start-ups.
- [Sage](http://www.sage.com/) (formerly Peachtree)
- [Xero](https://www.xero.com/)

  Online (cloud-hosted) accounting software for your small businesses.

I think they all offer on-line access, software and mobile apps.

Personally I would recommend FreeAgent, as I was using QuickBooks Online, but I've changed it.

---

For money management softwares (OS X compatible), you can try:

- [Money](http://www.jumsoft.com/money/) by Jumsoft

  Available for OS X, iPad and iPhone. Check for [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/jumsoft-money/).
- [iBank](http://www.iggsoftware.com/ibank/) by IGG Software

  A personal and small business financial manager designed to manage bank accounts, credit cards and investments, income and expenses. Check for [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/ibank/).

---

If you're looking for [open source softwares](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/989/3474), try:

- [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/)

  Small-business financial-accounting software. It allows you to track bank accounts, stocks, income and expenses.

Answer (score 1):

A useful accounting software for small businesses is Billbeez. Billbeez gives you a comprehensive overview of all of your financial data which allows you to easily track your payments and even alerts you in the case of missing and unpaid bills. This software essentially renders a bookkeeper useless.https://billbeez.com/?utm_source=stack_exchange&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=traffic

(Disclosure: I work for Billbeez)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Ragic](https://www.ragic.com) is a customizable database that's like Excel but more intuitive. They have a free [Accounting Lite](https://www.ragic.com/intl/en/blog/386/Accounting-Lite:-Accounting-and-Financial-Reports-Made-Easy#6) template you can try. If you don't want to deal with accounting entries, you can also build a simple sheet to record your revenue and expenses. You can drag and drop to generate [Line Graphs](https://www.ragic.com/intl/en/doc/55/Line-graph) and [Pivot Tables](https://www.ragic.com/intl/en/doc/51/Pivot-table) to gain insights from your data.
(Disclosure: I work for Ragic!)